# uninitialized constant Resque::Helpers when starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am getting an error when trying to start my rails application via `rails s`:

```
/Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/resque-scheduler-2.0.1/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:9:in `<class:Scheduler>': uninitialized constant Resque::Helpers (NameError)
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/resque-scheduler-2.0.1/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:7:in `<module:Resque>'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/resque-scheduler-2.0.1/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `rescue in block in require'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/nils/Uni/Masterarbeit/TweetTracker/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am using Rails 4 with Ruby 1.9.3. In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'resque', "~> 2.0.0.pre.1", github: "resque/resque"
gem 'resque-scheduler'
```

And the corresponding initializer:

```
# reestablish DB connection for the forked process within each job
Resque.after_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  resque_config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "resque.yml"))
  Resque.redis = resque_config[Rails.env]
end

# load resque config
resque_config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "resque.yml"))
Resque.redis = resque_config[Rails.env]

Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "jobs", "*.rb")].each { |file| require file }

require 'resque'
require 'resque/server'

# Load resque-scheduler schedule
require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'resque_scheduler/server'
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "schedule.yml"))
```

I have no idea what to do here. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think `resque_scheduler` is compatible with `resque -"~> 2.0.0.pre.1"`

because the `Helper` module no longer exists in `resque -"~> 2.0.0.pre.1"`

Check here [latest](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/helpers.rb)  and [1.x-stable](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque/helpers.rb) also see over [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/commit/e11724e73e48a639ba6004a1cab751caa870f90d)

Try using 1.x-stable branch

Hope this help